# vb6 legacy application freezing in Windows 10. Analyse wait chain shows csrss.exe

Tags: windows, random, crash, vb6, legacy

I've got a legacy VB6 application that runs on over 200 machines,mostly Windows 10 but also some 7 and 8.  Its working great on the vast majority of computers but it randomly crashes on a small number of Win 10 systems.  Randomly = between 1 and 5 times a day.

By crashing I mean it simply freezes.  No other message. Nothing in the event viewer.  The screen does grey out.

The crash occurs when a user clicks a button.  Not the same button each time.  The code behind the button(s) could be anything from opening a help form to running a search on an SQL Server.  There is no consistency.  I don't believe its actually the code causing the issue.

When I analyse the wait chain its always csrss.exe.
csrss.exe has been scanned to ensure its not a virus.  Its clean.

I know csrss.exe is something to do with the Windows sub system but its beyond my knowledge at the moment.

I'm looking for any help, ideas on the next step to finding the problem and of course curing it.

Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: VB6 applications are known to work almost flawlessly on WIN10, and as you probably imagined it would be impossible to even begin to guess what's going on without seeing a single line of code. seems like your only option is to get a win10 station to your office, and spend half a day trying to reproduce the bug. if you run PROCMON.exe (google 'sysinternal's procmon' )filtered on your application's process name, in the background, it would help you analyze the source of the problem. I suggest you start with making yourself a large cup of coffee. it's gonna be a long night.

Comment: I agree, the problem is something particular to your application, I have not seen any generic VB6 / Windows 10 issues either. I have however seen users misattribute all kinds of things to Win10.

Comment: In Task Manager right click it and choose Create Dump File (if it's at a clients). Live or on the dump file do a stack trace (`kb` which shows where the program is). See my answer here on using WinDbg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148571/vb6-debugging-compiled/38175005#38175005

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've gone with the large coffee and PROCMON.exe for now.  I've set up test bed where we're simulating clicks all over the application and will leave it running over the weekend.

Hopefully Monday morning brings some results.

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I've been suffering with the same issue. WinDbg and my own logs shows ADODB being the lock up point running a simple SELECT. Worse yet, it locks up SQL Server (running on another machine) for all other clients/all tables until I end task the original locked up client.  This is intermittent, multiple different locations and only on Win10.