# Cannot Register RESEDIT.DLL on Windows Server 2008

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2008, regsvr32, dllregistration

I have a legacy VB6 application that we are attempting to run on an RDP connection to a Windows 2008 Server.  All of my other legacy applications seem to run fine, but this one fails.  I've tried reinstalling the application from the Setup file, but it fails when it tries to register the file **`RESEDIT.DLL`**.  I've attempted to register the file manually using regsvr32, but that just gives me the following error:

`The module "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RESEDIT.DLL" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005.`

As I've researched this, I've found discussions about possible file dependency issues, but I've gone through every associated DLL in the setup package and they all register successfully.  I've made certain that I'm running the regsvr32 from an elevated command prompt, but it always comes up with the same error.

We installed the application on a Windows 7 VM, and it installed without error.  The `RESEDIT.DLL` file apparently registered successfully, and the application comes up without error.  However, running the application from the Windows Server 2008 system continues to throw errors.  It started with an error that says "Out of Memory" (Error #7), but now I'm getting one that says "ActiveX component can't create object" (Error #429), probably due to the different troubleshooting steps we've followed so far.

Does anyone know how to get `RESEDIT.DLL` to install and correctly register on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: If it's a 32 bit dll register it using c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.

Comment: Thanks, but that produces the same error.

Comment: Your error message just means FAIL, it doesn't give a cause.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been finding, but I can't for the life of me figure out any reason WHY it's failing.  I've been looking through event logs and all sorts of Google searches, but I can't determine what's causing it to fail in this specific environment.

Comment: Run Regsvr32 under Windbg. When it errors you'll get to see the call stack and the parameters to each function. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148571/vb6-debugging-compiled

Comment: If it's VB6's resedit.dll it isn't part of programs but the VB6 addin for Resource Editing. In VB6, Add-in menu, Addin Manager, choose VB6 Resource Editor, then Tools menu and Resource Editor.

Comment: Okay, I went through every DLL and OCX file used by the application and re-registered them.  I'm not sure what exactly I did, but it seems that I've somehow made it past the "Out of Memory" error I was getting.  Just to be safe, I went back into the source code for the application and found the reference to `RESEDIT.DLL` and removed it then recompiled.  Everything compiled successfully, so I tried again, but this time I'm getting a 429 error when the application is trying to make a method call to the FileSystemObject... Two steps forward, but one step back.

Comment: Try using late binding. `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. You shouldn't have that dll as part of your program as it's a system library. So only VB6 dlls should be included in your program, not Windows' dlls.

Comment: Are you running regsvr32 as admin? It can fail with that error message if not, in some cases.