# A VBS to enable and rename local admin account

Tags: vbscript

I am using the below vbs to enable and rename the Admin local account but is failing. It does not enable the account and does not rename it either. I do knot now why, it looks like a simple and easy script. Any clue?

```
sPwd = "hsc1234"

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colAccounts = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True and Name = 'Administrator'")

For Each objAccount in colAccounts
     MsgBox objAccount.Name
     objAccount.Disabled = False
     objAccount.Rename("HSC1")
     objAccount.SetPassword(sPwd)     

Next
```

Comment: `objAccount.Rename("HSC1")` returns a status code, what is it. `msgbox objAccount.Rename("HSC1")`

Comment: Thank you, how could I get the status code?

Comment: DID I NOT PUT IT IN MY COMMENT. Don't reply. You are supposed to be a programmer.

Comment: Wow sorry, I did not see your comment. The return code is 9

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393062(v=vs.85).aspx. Put wscript into WinDbg and get the API exception code. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148571/vb6-debugging-compiled

Comment: Hi, noodle. I reached a solution. Thanks for your help......and patient :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I could reach a solution. This solution can enable and rename the administrator account, and set the admin password as well. I got some issues with the Admin default account on W10, so I had to push the script in elevate mode.

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") ThenCreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

sPwd = "hsc1234"
strComputer = "."
sUser = "XXxx"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colAccounts = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True and Name = 'Administrator'")

For Each objAccount in colAccounts     
     objAccount.Disabled = False
     objAccount.Put_
     objAccount.Rename sUser
     'objAccount.SetPassword sPwd     
Next


Set oUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & sUser 
oUser.SetPassword sPwd 
oUser.Setinfo
```