# Return Code of batch script does not work in php

Tags: php, batch-file, exit-code, error-code

I have a strange situation with a very simple batch file which I want to run from PHP, and get the exit code of this.

If I run the batch script from `cmd.exe`, `echo %errorleve%` will return the correct exit code, in this case `12`.
From PHP script, exit code is `0`.

**my_batch.bat file**

```
@ECHO OFF

if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    exit /B 12
  )

  echo anything
)
```

**my_test.php**

```
<?php
exec('my_batch.bat',$result,$exitcode);
echo $result[0];
echo '<br />';
echo $exitcode;
```

**Output from cmd.exe**

```
D:\tools\xampp\htdocs\test>my_batch.bat
quitting

D:\tools\xampp\htdocs\test>echo %errorlevel%
12

D:\tools\xampp\htdocs\test>
```

**Output oh php:**

```
quitting
0
```

Thank you for your support

**EDIT 1**

verry strange, if I change the code with this version, all works OK

**my_batch.bat file**

```
@ECHO OFF

if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    SET MYERROR=12
    GOTO:END 
  )

  echo anything
)

:END
echo finished ... ERRORLEVEL "%MYERROR%"
exit /b %MYERROR%
```

Comment: Maybe exec the correct file? `my_batch.bat` vs `command.bat`

Comment: sorry,  the name was wrong typed. In my test all are running

Comment: The behavior I notice is that if the `exit /B 12` is outside the parentheses, then PHP gets the exitcode `12`, else it is `0`.

Comment: True, but the exist code works very well from CMD.exe. Why not working in this form with PHP.

Comment: As Nico Haase points, you are getting the exit code of the `cmd` process, not the one from the batch file. You can simply remove the `/B`

Comment: @MCND yah, seems to work without /B. But verry strange, a simple batch file with only `exit /B 12` works ok. So there is a strange behaviour with the place from where `exit /B code` is called.

Comment: Jus a sample, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41324747/2861476) answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41318027/2861476) question. Error levels, conditional execution and parenthesis don't always behave as we expect. If you add to that a separate process that executes the batch file then you will find behaviours as the one observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strange anomaly which occurs in batch file when additional commands exist in any level of parenthesis the `exit /b` is within.

Per your example, the `exit /b 12` is the last command in parenthesis level 2 but not the last command in parenthesis level 1.

In order for the batch file to exit completely and respond with the `exit` code you may turn the `if` statement into an `if/else` to segregate the commands from each other like so.

```
if "1"=="1" (
  if "1"=="1" (
    echo quitting
    exit /b 12
  ) else (
    echo anything
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the documentation at http://php.net/function.exec.php? It tells you that a call of `exec` spawns a instance of `cmd.exe` and this calls your batch script. Probably, this intermediate process won't pass the return code through?

A solution could be to use `proc_open`

Comment: same result with `proc_open`